# Is it possible to change the SID of a local user account manually?

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-domain

Let's say for argument's sake I wish to change the SID of a Windows local user account to one that appears on some hypothetical Active Directory domain. Is that possible? If so, how?

P.S. I don't actually need to know how... all I care about is that it is demonstrably possible and that theoretically some malicious user on the network could do this... and how much skill they would need to do so.

Answer (score 4):

**It's technically possible** to do so, by editing the SAM database (under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Security` in the Registry), but it requires understanding of the binary formats used there. **There exist tools that do this**, such as [NewSid](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897418.aspx) – although it usually did the *opposite* of what you're looking for, but nevertheless it *was* able to change the machine SID and user SIDs, computer-wide. The NewSid webpage has some information on how this is done.

However, it won't achieve much. **The SID is only used locally.** It does not matter what SID you have; it will not give you access to any additional network resources. (This is similar to **[the arguments given by SysInternals](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/11/03/3291024.aspx)** when they discontinued the NewSid utility – it would create a fresh machine SID if you had cloned machines with identical SIDs, but it was explained that having identical machine SIDs, and therefore identical user SIDs, **has zero effect on network security.**)

For network authentication, Active Directory uses [Kerberos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol)) and sometimes the (now-deprecated) [NTLM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTLM), both of which authenticate users using their password or similar credentials.

Comment: Goodness knows what would happen if you tried to change the local machine SID to be the same as the domain SID.  You could expect all sorts of things to go wrong.  As you say, though, it wouldn't give you any special privilege in the domain.

Comment: In fringe use cases changing a local account's SID could potentially be useful, such as when using a failover cluster with shared storage and local accounts. If there are local account specific ACLs on the shared storage, and it was impracticable to add the ACLs for the local account of the 2nd node of the cluster, for instance if the failover cluster's service/application created new files with a non inherited ACL.

Comment: @MuhFugen: If you have a failover cluster, wouldn't you usually also have AD?

Comment: Yes? I was referring to local accounts.

Answer (score 1):

You can't the **S**ecurity **ID**endtifier is built based off of enviroment variables at the time of creation. They are unique, and are not over writable.

[If you need more information:](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961998.aspx)

> The SID for an account or group created in one domain of an enterprise never matches the SID for an account or group created in another domain of the same enterprise.

I would suspect that IF you ever managed to do it, the domain would see it as somesort of oddity and deny access or do other odd things.

Comment: That's just what I was hoping to hear. My manager just needs to hear it from someone other than me as he thinks this can be changed no problem... which I say is BS :D

Comment: They are technically overwriteable. This happens whenever you run Microsoft sysprep

Comment: And you can see duplicate SIDs in environments when someone has imaged a computer (or cloned a VM) which didnt have sysprep's generalize function ran on it beforehand.