# How to make two laptops running Windows 10 use the same user id for sharing files?

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, access-control, uuid

I have several Windows 10 laptops with a (Sabrent) USB disk cloner (and 2.5" (SATA?) disks I can insert into it) that I plug into each to move partitions back and forth and I want essentially one user running on all of them, so that no matter which one I use I have the same access to the files when the disk cloner is plugged into it and I copy the partition locally.  (Details below.)

I'm pretty certain it is some form of UUID S-99-999-99999999 that each OS has, even though they all use the same Microsoft account for logging in (and the local account name is the same on each also).  I am not afraid of editing the registry if that is what is required to get them to line up.

Details:

I start with the disk cloner plugged into system1 and I use minitool partition wizard to copy the r: partition onto a 2.5" disk in the cloner say partition p:.  I then disconnect the controller from system1 and connect it to system2 and I copy from the disk in the cloner (partition p:) onto system2 as drive r:.  Mostly that works, but sometimes I find that the files I created on system1 are now marked read-only on system2 or have unknown users when I go to access the security information, even though when looking at those files on system1 the info is just for my local account.  It clearly seems that although the local accounts have the same name on both systems, they have different UUIDs (or something).

Note, that I don't have a domain or a server, just laptops.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [windows - Is it possible to change the SID of a local user account manually? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/581042/is-it-possible-to-change-the-sid-of-a-local-user-account-manually)

Comment: Having the same Microsoft Account on multiple machines facilitates fairly easy file sharing using Public Folders.

Comment: I read the document on NewSID and the duplicate SID problem is actually the feature I want.  I want to move portable drives from one system to the other and have the same accounts (I only have one.  They are both access them (actually all 5 are) my "single user" machines.  So, I actually want the SID to be "insecure" that way.

Comment: Yes, but it's a pain when moving directory structures in the TB size.  I really want "Sneaker Net" as we used to call it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the SID prefix for local accounts is unique for each Windows installation. (It's not an UUID, though it *is* randomly generated.) Each account's SID is made by suffixing the machine SID prefix with an incrementing ID (the RID).

The sharing that you ask is generally only possible for Active Directory domain accounts (which use a domain SID prefix) or if both computers were installed by cloning one to another. And no, you can't really change the machine SID prefix by hand-editing the registry... at most, you could only change an account's RID, which is the last number, but that still won't make it the same account.

But you *don't need* it to be the same SID anyway – file permissions (ACLs) on NTFS can deal with this, all you need is grant "Full Access" to both accounts. (That is, go to machine 1, grant access to yourself, move to machine 2, do the same.) Each machine will show the other's ACL entries as belonging to unknown SIDs, but that's perfectly fine – it won't automatically remove or otherwise disturb them. And if the entry is inheritable, even the unknown SIDs will be copied to newly created files without causing any problems.

Additionally, certain subjects – such as the built-in "Users" and "Administrators" groups, or the magic "Everyone" identifier – actually have a [fixed SID](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/well-known-sids) on all systems. So if you grant access to "Users" on one system, this will be recognized on *all* systems that the disk is connected to.

(For removable disks, it is fine to just grant full access to "Everyone" and remove *all* user-specific ACL entries including the "CREATOR OWNER" template, if you want.)

Comment: The OS drive as made by cloning from my "master" computer, which is why I was surprised when the additional files/partitions that I moved on a removable disk didn't work.  I will follow your suggestion and try to fix the ACLs.