# Sharing NTFS partition with 2 Windows installations

Tags: windows, permissions, ntfs

I currently have a setup that looks like this:

- SSD with Windows 10 installation and most program data
- HDD with holding larger document folders (such as pictures and videos) or large program data

The way I set up the HDD is by manually creating empty Program Files and User directories on the HDD and replicated the NTFS permission scheme from the main SSD. Then I created junctions for the specific user document subfolders that contain the large directories that make more sense to live in the HDD. This last bit is just for the sake of convenience.

I'm hoping to do a dual boot installation of Windows 11 on a different SSD and have it access the same document directories on the HDD in a similar fashion. What would be a good way to handle the HDD permissions in a way that the directories are accessible from both Windows installations?

Things I've considered:

- Making a user with a specific SID on the Windows 11 installation ([but the user SID is seemingly tied to the machine SID, and changing that is discouraged](https://superuser.com/questions/581042/is-it-possible-to-change-the-sid-of-a-local-user-account-manually)).
- Just adding the Windows 11 groups/users into the permissions for the HDD directories. Probably the easiest, but will result in having a bunch of unrecognized SIDs in there on each of the OSs.

Comment: What third OS will own the common partition and keep track of what the other two will write to it one at a time and only when the other is not running?

Comment: Your outline is just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think your idea is practical.

If two systems can write to the same file at asynchronous moments, collisions can be generated. This happens to me from time to time. I forget that I changed the file in the other computer and Sync Back Pro warns me of the collision and I must manually choose.

How will you handle this when only one system is running a one moment (that is dual-boot) and there is no way to handle the collision automatically.

Then it is also not at all clear which of your two operating systems will own the single partition and how the other will get to it.

Summary: this is not a practical idea and if you have some files you deem common, put them on a third drive (external USB drive) and mount the drive to the working system.

Comment: The question says it's going to be a dual-boot system, so there will only be one system at a time using the drive, or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, and I addressed the dual boot situation in my answer. I also edited for complete clarity. Thanks

Comment: Ah, do you mean it could be that OS1 is hibernated while some program P is running with an open file F. Meanwhile, OS2 is run and some program running under that alters the file F. Then the next time OS1 is brought out of hibernation, program P now has a version of file F in RAM which does not have the changes on disk made under OS2?

Comment: While I understand the issues with caching/hibernation... Surely there must be a better approach to preventing them than taking an internal SATA drive and putting it in an external USB enclosure?

Using a partition with different OSs (not concurrently) isn't probably that rare of a use case for it to not have a well established solution.

Comment: There is also a problem with Fast Startup.

Comment: But Fast Startup being essentially the exact same problem than hibernation. If there's a solution for that (other than making the drive external through an enclosure) it surely would apply to both.

Comment: You are better off not using a single partition for disparate operating systems.  I do not believe it will work at all. Probably more difficulties than a person could reasonably handle.